# Write to an existing XLS file using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, file-io

I want to write an user input to an existing column in an `*.xls` file but nothing happend to the existing file. I can write my user input to a dataframe but can't export it to the `*.xls`.
How to do this?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

inp = input("Input: ")
userinput = {'USER': [inp],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(userinput, columns = ['USER'])
```

here I get my Dataframe. Columnname: `USER` and content: `inp`

```
data = pd.read_excel (r'H:\testfile.xls')
```

... to read the existing `*.xls` file
At this point I don't know how to add the content to an existing column in the `testfile.xls` (the column in the `testfile.xls` has the same name "`USER`")

Comment: I don't know if I follow, but: `read` means read file into memory; to write to a file, use `df.to_excel(<filename>)`.  I would suggest using a test filename first

Comment: @anon01 tried it, But it overide the whole content. i want to add the content from the user input to an existing column in testfile.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right:
df  is the user input DF
data is the existing excel

You need to use append or merge to create a new DF combining the two and then write to Excel. Something like:

```
newDF = df.append(data)
newDF.to_excel(<new filename>)
```

Comment: sorry found a typo in my code. "inp" is the input / "userinput" is the name of the column and the content from "inp" / "df" create the dataframe / "data" reads the content from the existing file. When I read that it occurs to me that I could merge them together